# Why doesn't pip list show modules from all directories in sys.path?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pip

I have installed pandas 1.0.1 from pypi.org. More recently, I built and installed pandas 1.1.0 from source.

Here is my sys.path -

```
Python 3.7.5 (default, Nov  7 2019, 10:50:52) 
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['', '/usr/lib/python37.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.7', '/usr/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload', '/home/sss/dev/venv/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages', '/home/sss/dev/venv/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas-1.1.0.dev0+986.g8786e0282-py3.7-linux-x86_64.egg']
```

and I see these pandas directories in `site-packages` -

```
/home/sss/dev/venv/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/
/home/sss/dev/venv/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas-1.0.1.dist-info/
/home/sss/dev/venv/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas-1.1.0.dev0+986.g8786e0282-py3.7-linux-x86_64.egg/
/home/sss/dev/venv/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas-1.1.0.dev0+986.g8786e0282-py3.7-linux-x86_64.egg/EGG-INFO/
/home/sss/dev/venv/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas-1.1.0.dev0+986.g8786e0282-py3.7-linux-x86_64.egg/pandas/
```

Why does pip list show only version 1.0.1? How do I import version 1.1.0?

Comment: `pip` lists only what was installed with `pip`. How did you installed `pandas`? If it wasn't `pip install .` pip doesn't know about that module.

Comment: I followed the instructions https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas and executed `python setup.py install` in the cloned github directory. I just discovered a way to list this version with pip - `pip list --path /home/sss/dev/venv/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas-1.1.0.dev0+986.g8786e0282-py3.7-linux-x86_64.egg` which shows `pandas  1.1.0.dev0+986.g8786e0282` - but how can I import it?

Comment: Uninstall `pandas 1.0.1` first. You have `/home/sss/dev/venv/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas-1.1.0.dev0+986.g8786e0282-py3.7-linux-x86_64.egg` in `sys.path` so you just `import pandas`.

Comment: that worked, thanks